# Attribute Error while using cx_Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze, python-3.6

while creating exe of my python game . I got the following error[image: Error]

my code in setup.py is

```
import cx_Freeze
import os

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\Vinayak Singla\\Appdata\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\Vinayak Singla\\Appdata\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\tcl\\tk8.6"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("pong.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="Pongy",
    options={"build_exe": {"packages":["pygame","sys","random","time"],"include_files":["boing.wav","out.wav"]}},
    executables = executables
)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need a `version` in your setup script. Like:

```
cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="Pongy",
    version='1.0',
    options={"build_exe": {"packages":["pygame","sys","random","time"],"include_files":["boing.wav","out.wav"]}},
    executables = executables
)
```

Hope this will solve your problem.