# cx_Freeze: “No module named 'codecs'” Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, cx-freeze

I am currently making a game using pygame module.
I have followed the following links' directions.
https://pythonprogramming.net/converting-pygame-executable-cx_freeze/

I have solved some problems such as KeyError [KeyError: 'TCL_Library' when I use cx_Freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533803/keyerror-tcl-library-when-i-use-cx-freeze)
AttributeError 
[Attribute Error while using cx_Freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45906514/attribute-error-while-using-cx-freeze)

The build of setup.py has been done, but as I run the exe file of the game, it crashes with Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec

```
    Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jinju\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'codecs'
```

I have read the previous questions answered in Linux kernel ([cx_Freeze: "No module named 'codecs'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961944/cx-freeze-no-module-named-codecs)), but I want to know what should I do with my Windows 10 kernel.

I use Python 3.5.3 downloaded through the python homepage, cx_Freeze-5.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl downloaded automatically through pip, pygame 1.9.3 through downloading whl with pip.

the setup.py file

```
import cx_Freeze, os

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("quatris.py")]

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\jinju\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\jinju\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\tcl\tk8.6'

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "QUATRIS",
    version = '1.0',
    options={"build_exe": {"packages":["pygame"], "include_files":['ab_main.wav', 'ct_main.wav', 'f3_main.wav',
                                                                    'ff_main.wav', 'gta4_soviet.wav',
                                                                    'h3_neverforget.wav', 'h_onefinaleffort.wav',
                                                                    'm_sweden.wav', 'p1_stillalive.wav',
                                                                    'p2_caramiaaddio.wav', 'smb_1-up.wav',
                                                                    'smb_bump.wav', 'smb_coin.wav', 'smb_gameover.wav',
                                                                    'smb_mariodie.wav', 'smb_overworld.wav',
                                                                    'smb_pause.wav', 'tes4o_main.wav',
                                                                    'tes5s_dragonborn.wav', 'tes5s_farhorizons.wav',
                                                                    'tetris.wav', 'tloz_intro.wav', 'tw3wh_main.wav']}},
    executables = executables)
```

I tried to look at the **init**.py file and the codecs.py file. When I try to import codecs,

```
module 'codecs' has no attribute 'register'
```

this thing comes out.

```
# Register the search_function in the Python codec registry
codecs.register(search_function)
```

This is the part where the error occurs in the **init**.py file.

Comment: Your quatris.py runs without errors doesn't it?

Comment: Even with `cx_freeze` 5.1.1 I was still getting this error. I followed the traceback all the way up and realized it was a particular module that was the source of the error. In my case it was `tweepy` module that was the source. I didn't need that module in the exe so I just commented it out and no longer got that error.

Answer (score 4):

This was a bug in cx_Freeze which has now been corrected: https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/commit/9c98492911d4c75587d3687206d11812b48bf144

Comment: I just installed via `pip install cx_Freeze --upgrade` (v5.1) and am having the same problem.  When I try to run the .exe file it crashes with the same error, `No module named 'codecs'`.  Adding `import codec` to the top of my python file had no effect.  I'm using Python 3.6.1 on windows with an amd64 cpu.

Comment: Yes, you have to build from source until I release version 5.1.1!

Comment: cx_Freeze 5.1.1 was just released with this fix included in it.

Comment: I am having the same issue with cx_Freeze 5.1.1

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach but not elegant can be to place

```
if not True:
    import codecs
```

somewhere in your code.

Comment: inside setup.py you mean?

Comment: @MinhaArmadaJu No, somewhere in your normal Python code.

Comment: I pasted your code into my main.py code and built the game again, but the error still there.

Comment: For me , I directly imported the codecs at the top of my main and it worked.