# Converting python script into executable file, no module named 'codecs'

Tags: python, exe, executable

I have converted Python code into a `.exe` file using `cx_Freeze`. When I opened the `.exe` file it wrote an error :

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\encodings__init__.py", line 31,
    in ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'codecs'
```

This error appears, but the program doesn't close down itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cx\_Freeze: “No module named 'codecs'” Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223944/cx-freeze-no-module-named-codecs-windows-10)

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading cx_Freeze. This was fixed in recent versions.

Source: [cx_Freeze: “No module named 'codecs'” Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223944/cx-freeze-no-module-named-codecs-windows-10)